# Unable to include QTimer

Tags: qt, timer, qtimer

I am a beginner at programming and I am unable to include **QTimer** class of Qt 5.6 in my project. I reinstalled qt twice but its not working yet.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't find QTimer"? Who can't find it? Is there an error? Are you personally looking for something - if so, what? Is the compiler looking for something? What is your problem - be *specific*

Comment: What do you mean exactly. Did you try writing `#include <QTimer>` and the compiler said something like "unable to find QTimer"? Did you start typing and it didn't show up in the auto-complete list? Please be more specific, that will help people find an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Did you add QT += core on your .pro file? And #include < QTimer> in your source file.

Include files get available when you add corresponding modules in your pro files. Required modules are documented on top of the class documentation you want to use.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmodules.html

Comment: `qt += core` may not be enough, one also needs `config += Qt`

Comment: already had qt += core and #include <QTimer>, but still i am not able to find it, thanks anyway both of you